# Calculate distance between various points of a dataframe with python, in a two-dimensional, Cartesian plane system

Tags: python, sqrt

## I am trying to create a new column with the distance from the first point, to the rest of the points, but I get an error. The coordinates are Cartesian.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"X":[53100.6428, 46359.2159, 63286.7709, 178117.7184, 178041.0474], "Y":[32012.7328, 31168.1051, 1168.1051, -153941.4367, -157366.9088]})

df

>>> df
             X            Y
0   53100.6428   32012.7328
1   46359.2159   31168.1051
2   63286.7709    1168.1051
3  178117.7184 -153941.4367
4  178041.0474 -157366.9088

import math

df['Dist'] = math.sqrt(((df.loc[0, 'X']) - (df['X']))**2 + ((df.loc[0, 'Y']) - (df['Y']))**2)

>>> df['Distancia'] = math.sqrt(((df.loc[0, 'X']) - (df['X']))**2 + ((df.loc[0, 'Y']) - (df['Y']))**2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Laura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 112, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

## What can i do to fix it? Is there any better way?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `math` package is not able to work on arrays or dataframe columns. Instead of `math.sqrt`, try to use

```
import numpy as np
df['Dist'] = np.sqrt(((df.loc[0, 'X']) - (df['X']))**2 + ((df.loc[0, 'Y']) - (df['Y']))**2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution - use `pow`:

```
first_x = df.loc[0, "X"]
first_y = df.loc[0, "Y"]

((df.X - first_x) ** 2 + (df.Y - first_y)).pow(.5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know the pow function.

Comment: If that's the right answer, please accept it for future users ...